# PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function getBackend() on a non-object in

Tags: magento-1, fatal-error

I am getting an error on my websites home page including a custom attribute from my theme.

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getBackend() on a
>   non-object in
>   /chroot/home/afgclass/WEBSITEDOMAIN/html/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php

Can you guys please help any suggestions? Sadly I have no backups ;(

Comment: It's hard to tell what are you doing. However check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070652/magento-fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-getbackend-on-a-non-object-in)

Answer (score 1):

Have you done any custom code in your application?

Somehow you are using wrong attribute Id which is being checked by below function -

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Abstract.php
public function isAttributeStatic($attribute)
{
    $attrInstance       = $this->getAttribute($attribute);
    $attrBackendStatic  = $attrInstance->getBackend()->isStatic();
    return $attrInstance && $attrBackendStatic;
}
```

So check your customization thoroughly.

Got this reference from
[Alan Storm](http://magento-quickies.alanstorm.com/post/91985359245/call-to-a-member-function-getbackend-on-a)